# Are group time estimates standard?

Tags: agile, scrum, time

Our team assigns time estimates to tasks (not stories) in a group setting, so one of us will give an estimate that then anyone who picks up the stories has to meet or else gets questioned about it. Everyone has different levels of experience with the code so the estimate from one person might be way lower than it would take someone else.

Is this a standard practice? I have always been used to provide my individual estimates after I pick up a story and have done a small amount of research on what would need to be changed. There's also an implicit pressure to provide lower than real estimates in a group setting where there's an undertone of "this shouldn't take you more than x amount of time to complete".

Comment: "Everyone has different levels of experience with the code so the estimate from one person might be way lower than it would take someone else." This is totally obvious, and if the team's process doesn't acknowledge/incorporate that reality, then that's a real failure of management.

Comment: I guess you left something out here. Why would you estimate in a group setting when you don't discuss the estimations as a group first?

Comment: What's described here is not just a disaster waiting to happen. This is an imminent disaster that happens to be waiting.

Answer (score 9):

There are only problems here.

What you describe is not group estimation. There are consensus-based estimation techniques - [Wideband Delphi was developed in the 1970s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wideband_delphi) and [Planning Poker rose to popularity in the early 2000s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_poker). In these techniques, the team comes together to discuss and estimate attributes of the work, such as time or complexity. The team also accounts for variations in skills, experience, and knowledge by talking about the job. Just because everyone is sitting in a room together doesn't make this technique a team-based, group-based, or consensus-based estimation.

The organization also falls into the trap of treating estimates as targets or commitments. [Steve McConnell's Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605351) has chapters that address this anti-pattern and mitigations, such as ensuring that you express the assumptions that went into your estimation and the existing uncertainties.

The team, as well as the broader organization, needs to rethink the estimation strategy. That includes if explicit estimation makes sense. In my experience, explicit estimation is often wasteful, and eliminating it as a practice can be beneficial.

Answer (score 6):

> Our team assigns time estimates to tasks (not stories) **in a group setting**, [..]
> [..] so **one of us will give an estimate**

This is contradictory. If *one* person gives an estimate, it's not done "in a group setting", that's an individual estimate *with an audience*.

This doesn't defeat the question, but it does suggest that you're not describing your process accurately, which is liable to attract wrong advice or wrong information when querying online.

> There's also an implicit pressure to provide lower than real estimates in a group setting where there's an undertone of "this shouldn't take you more than x amount of time to complete".

Investigate the source of that pressure and disable it. Very simply put, reporting a lower estimate than is realistically needed hurts **everyone**.

- Developers are put under unreasonable pressure
- Product owners are given incorrect deadlines
- Managers end up looking like they're managing an underperforming team

The only reason to actively underreport development time is a short-term optics boost, at the cost of everyone in the long term. If there is an actor knowingly causing this, they are hurting the company and everyone involved in the project and need to be stopped.

If this is a workplace habit without an explicit source pushing for this, then it's more a matter of collectively acknowledging the issue and moving on from it together.
*Cynically, this approach can also allow for "amnesty" for previously bad actors who don't intend to die on this hill now that the problem has been publicly called out.*

> I have always been used to provide my individual estimates after I pick up a story and have done a small amount of research on what would need to be changed.

Estimating your own work after it has been assigned to you will give you a reasonable assessment based on the implementing developer's skillset, but it also causes some inefficiencies.

- If done for all tasks, it significantly reduces the purpose of a team. Now you're just a group of individual developers rather than a team working together towards the problem.
- It is very difficult to figure out if you assigned the work to the right dev. Would another dev have been able to tackle this faster? As the product owner or team leader, this isn't obvious from receiving one developer's personal estimate.
- It shuts out the [wisdom of the crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd), both in relation to receiving a statistically more correct average estimate, and to spot any significant outliers. The latter usually indicates a different understanding of the requirements, a different understanding of the current state of the codebase, or a deep disagreement about development practices. All of these are worth digging into to find out why the developers on the same team disagree so much.

> Everyone has different levels of experience with the code so the estimate from one person might be way lower than it would take someone else.

If working in a **team**, an inexperienced dev should be able to lean on the more experienced devs. With those experienced devs' assistance, the time to delivery will be shorter than if that inexperienced dev did the work on their own cognizance. If that is not a true fact, then your team has some deep-running communication issues that need to be addressed.

The average team estimate should statistically reflect the average team member's time to resolution. And if this isn't the case, your team is likely going to be inaccurate in a consistent manner (e.g. always over/underestimating to a similar order of magnitude), which is something a team leader/product owner/scrum master can account for in future estimations.

If your team is incapable of providing a coherent consensus and *reasonably consistent* approximation, this is again indicative of team issues that need resolving.

---

The main point of feedback that I think is relevant for you to hear is not that the estimation process is supposed to give you a perfect result, nor should you design it with that goal in mind.

Instead, the estimation effort should be designed in a way that **it highlights misunderstood requirements, consistent inconsistencies and deeper issues in the team**. This then opens the door to addressing those issues, which in turn will improve the estimates you're going to receive.

Estimates aren't about getting this one as correct as it can possibly be. Estimates are about the team aligning themselves and averaging out over a larger scope than just one dev.

If you keep trying to have one dev get their personal estimate right, then you're not working in a team environment. I'm not saying that this is wrong, but I would not sell this as "in a group setting" in the way that your question currently does. A team is more than the sum of its parts.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common practice, but you're doing it for the wrong reason. It's not about grilling people who don't meet a group-establish estimate.

Group software estimation (in all its various forms, e.g. planning poker, T-shirt sizing, Fibonacci points etc.) exists to tap into the power of the [wisdom of the crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd). Some people have an optimistic bias, some are more pessimistic, but on the whole, large enough crowds average out to being roughly correct.

Comment: What the OP describes is the opposite of that: *one* person estimates and *everybody* needs to meet those estimates. The wisdom of the crowd works because biases even each other out on average, but that only works *if you are actually looking at the average*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh wow, that's even worse than I thought on first-reading.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people engage in practices without really having a grasp of what functions those practices are performing.

Estimation is done for a variety of reasons which I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Costing and charging for a particular task;
2. Driving the pace of work;
3. Coordinating a larger project; and
4. Intervening when work has gone off track.

Each of these reasons is different, can be of very different importance in different business contexts, and the estimate would not necessarily be made by the developer in all cases.

Without being specific about the business context and the functions estimates are performing (or intended to perform) for your organisation, it's almost impossible to say whether a particular practice is normal (and desirable) or not.